# Execute a pure binary file on Android

Tags: c++, android-ndk, exe

Is there a way to run a binary executable file (compile with NDK), on Android?

```
/* #includes #defines ... */

int main(){
    // Do something when this is executed
    return 0;
}
```

I want it to run independant from the VM. As in not inside an activity, just a binary that runs directly on the proc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
adb push exename /data/bin/exename
#next line might be needed if you are developing on Windows
adb shell chmod 777 /data/bin/exename
adb shell /data/bin/exename
```

But your device has to be rooted. (It also works on emulator.)

Comment: Ok so will this compile into an APK that can be installed directly or is the exe wrapped in a Davlik format just for initialization?

Comment: No and no. Pure binary file is just a binary file. You can use `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)` instead of `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` in your `Android.mk` to build such executable with NDK.

Comment: is there any way to execute binary from java file(i.e. at run time).

Comment: Does this still work on Jelly Bean? The question [Run native ARM executable on Jelly Bean](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29615/4229) seems to imply this no longer works.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering to your doubt in the first answer mentioned by Andrey.

Try the codes given by him.

```
adb push exename /data/bin/exename
```

It is used to push the binary file named 'exename' to the execuatable path on Android.

```
adb shell chmod 777 /data/bin/exename
```

This line is not required in linux. Its used to change the mode. 
The first 7 stands for 'user', next for 'group' and the last for 'other'.
Changing the numbers would CHange the MODe of each group mentioned above.
7 represents - read, write and execute.
6 represents - read, write and NO execute.

```
adb shell /data/bin/exename
```

This code is used to execute the binary. Which inturn means that its being used in the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks Anoop! Looks like it all works pretty smoothly via shell commands. Can you not execute in via interaction on the mobile? Is there any way you can build some sort of link to a shell script which will result in an execution of the binary (as in on the actual mobile - suposedly this has to be done via Java)?

Comment: Oh, I am afraid I couldnot help you out. I didnot understand your question completely and to whatever I understood, I have no idea about it.
Could you make it a bit more clear so that I too could try searching for it.

Comment: Sorry. What i mean is, yuo can execute a binary on Android via shell comands (adb shell chmod 777 is a command run on the kernel shell). Shell scripts are files that basically contain a load of shell commands. Is there any way I can execute a shell script on an Android device, instead of having to type the shell commands myself...?

Comment: ok. I dont know whether there is a way to execute a shellscript in android device. There must be a way, will look into it.
What I do normally to reduce typing all these commands is to create a text file with all the script commands in the pc and then run the file in terminal. It serves my purpose. Did that help?

Comment: Do mind to upvote the answers that you find yourselves useful. :)